# Не могу установить monodevelop из-за зависимостей в kali linux subsystem Windows 10

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Хочу установить monodevelop, но из-за зависимости libjpeg8 не могу.

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgdiplus : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Попытался установить libjpeg8.

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libjpeg8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libjpeg8' has no installation candidate
```

Вот файл sourses.list:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
#deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: ну так оно хочет libjpeg**8**, а Вы пытаетесь установить libjpeg.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, но так тоже не выходит. Я изменил

Comment: правда там пишет, что пакеты уже сломаны. Для начала неплохо это починить - `apt install -f` А потом уже снова пробовать установить monodevelop

Comment: @KoVadif `apt install -f` не помогло

Comment: вот это сообщение "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." пропало?

Comment: @KoVadim нет ничего не изменилось